# Variable is not a CFString how to remove this

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have value which i am storing in the var it gives error

```
Date*aDate=[appDelegate.dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSInteger test=aDate.date;
cell.text=test;
```

This is the Date class

#### Date.h

```
@interface Date : NSObject {
    NSInteger *date;

}
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger *date;

@end
```

#### Date.m

```
#import "Date.h"


@implementation Date
@synthesize date;

-(id)init{
    self=[super init];
}

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dict {
    self.date = [dict valueForKey:@"date"];

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: That's cool give us 3 lines of code with no error and ask us to read your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this.

```
Date*aDate=[appDelegate.dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSInteger test=aDate.date;
cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",test];
```

Since u cannot set integer to cell label.

Comment: I have to ask some thing if you can help i  have fetch all data from array and i want to show data in sectioned tableview

Comment: Kindly go thru the [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) first.